# Ping to same host name returns an unexpected address

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, ping

I have 2 win machines in a LAN (at home). Say their names and addresses are:

`MYSTATION1` - `192.168.100.102`  - Win 7

`MYSTATION2` - `192.168.100.109`  - Win 10 home

If I ping `MYSTATION1` from the command line in `MYSTATION1` it returns `192.168.100.102`. So I would expect pinging `MYSTATION2` from the command line in `MYSTATION2` would return `192.168.100.109`. Instead, it returns a completely unexpected address: `169.254.19.171`.

I'm not so versed on networking stuff but my intuition says the first example is the correct thing to happen, i.e. pinging local host name should return its own IP address, am I assuming right?

Why is `MYSTATION2` resolving the address differently? I already flushed dns on `MYSTATION2` but yet ping resolves to `169.254.19.171`.

Below is what I get on `MYSTATION2` for `ping` and `ipconfig /all`

Ping:

```
Haciendo ping a MYSTATION2 [169.254.19.171] con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 169.254.19.171: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 169.254.19.171: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 169.254.19.171: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 169.254.19.171: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128

Estadísticas de ping para 169.254.19.171:
Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
(0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
Mínimo = 0ms, Máximo = 0ms, Media = 0ms
```

ipconfig /all

```
Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : <thought I should remove it?>
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
   Dirección IPv6 . . . . . . . . . . : 2806:2f0:9000:34b3:45e6:9db0:edfd:3884(Preferido)
   Dirección IPv6 temporal. . . . . . : 2806:2f0:9000:34b3:5022:5608:e978:17de(Obsoleto)
   Dirección IPv6 temporal. . . . . . : 2806:2f0:9000:34b3:b076:c358:4295:2579(Obsoleto)
   Dirección IPv6 temporal. . . . . . : 2806:2f0:9000:34b3:f959:f7af:9c7c:c9e7(Preferido)
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::45e6:9db0:edfd:3884%4(Preferido)
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.109(Preferido)
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concesión obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : viernes, 8 de noviembre de 2019 09:53:54 a. m.
   La concesión expira . . . . . . . . . . . : jueves, 14 de noviembre de 2019 10:39:55 a. m.
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : fe80::1%4
                                       192.168.100.1
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 47481303
   DUID de cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-70-83-1A-D4-81-D7-AE-CF-B4
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%4
                                       192.168.100.1
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado
```

Comment: You may have more than one network adapter on `MYSTATION2` - Is the output of `ipconfig /all` complete?

Comment: PING shows 169.254.19.171 address exists somewhere in OS whereas IPCONFIG not. This may be: some software (tunneling, proxying, including virus/backdoor) or IP stack error, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

169.254 is the no connection address.  MYSTATION2 says above it is not connected.  On this station run TCP/IP Reset

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

I would also update the Network Card driver as well on this machine.

Comment: *169.254 is the no connection address.* That is wrong. This is self-autoassigned address when no answer from any DHCP was obtained. See APIPA description...

Comment: Sorry for mis-speaking but resetting TCP/IP is still a typical solution for this.

Comment: Agreed, it is the first what one must try to do for issue fix. But I estimate the probability that it will help less than 50%...

Comment: Thank you @John, it worked as you said.

Comment: And thank you @Akina for clarifying on terminology.

Comment: Glad this worked for you